# What is the difference between these two sum notations?

Tags: summation

I often see sum-notation wirtten in one of the following ways:

[image]

AND:

[image]

Is there any difference between the two, or is it just a matter of style? thanks.

Comment: I think it's just formatting.  For MathJax, for instance, you get $\sum_{i=1}^{100}i$ in line, but $\displaystyle {\sum_{i=1}^{100}i}$ if it is offset (or, as here, marked as "display style").

Comment: I think the second is a typesetting error. I find it hard to read.  It's interestion to note in MathJax \$\sum_{i=1}^{100} i\$ is rendered as $\sum_{i=1}^{100} i$ but \$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100} i\$ is rendered as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100} i$, the latter is easier to read but harder to type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in concept.

I like the first one better because of its format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like for many mathematical symbols, sometimes the two forms are used equivalently, other times the different layout is useful to help and distinguish different definitions of *Sum*.

While the first layout is almost generally reserved for the "ordinary" sum, the second is used by many people (including me) to indicate the sum in the meaning of [Antidifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum), computed for $i$ ranging from $1$ to $100$.
That is
$$
f(x) = \Delta F(x) = F(x + 1) - F(x)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad F(x) = \Delta ^{\, - 1} f(x) = \sum\nolimits_{\,x} {f(x)} 
$$
which for integral upper and lower limits returns **almost** the same value as the ordinary sum
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\,i = 1\;}^{\,100} {f(i)}  = F(100) - F(1) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{99} {f(i)} 
$$

But with the Antidifference interpretation, we can give a meaning also to a sum having the upper bound less than the lower one
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\,i = 100\;}^{\;1} { =  - f(i)} \sum\nolimits_{\,i = 1\;}^{\,100} {f(i)} 
$$
and, if $F(x)$ is defined also for real or complex values of the argument, then the sum has a meaning also for real/complex bounds
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\,i = 1\;}^{\,y} {f(i)}  = F(y) - F(1)\quad 
$$
so quite a different concept.