# Prove by Induction on k. using Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers, discrete-calculus

$$F_{k-2}+F_{k-4}+...+F_{k\,mod\,2+2}=F_{k-1}-1, \quad \quad if\: k\geq2.$$

This equation is to prove by induction on $k;$ the left-hand side is zero when $k$ is $2$ or $3$. Therefore $k_{1}$ is the greedily chosen value described earlier, and the representation must be unique.

Here is my Attempt.

I have attempted to solve this problem using induction, Please if anyone confirms that my attempt is true for induction step. Or If someone helps me with this answer if anything goes wrong.

$$F_{k-2}+F_{k-4}+...+F_{k\,mod\,2+2}=F_{k-1}-1 \quad \quad if\,k\geq2$$

My Attempt:
Base case $k=2$
$$F_{2-2}+F_{2-4}+...+F_{2\,mod \,2+2}=F_{2-1}-1$$
As $2\, mod\,2=0$
therefore,
$$F_{0}+F_{-2}+...+F_{0+2}=F_{1}-1$$
$$F_{0}+F_{-2}+...+F_{2}=F_{1}-1$$
As $F_{0}=0,\,F_{-2}=-1,\,F_{2}=1,\,and\,F_{1}=1\,$therefore,
$$0+(-1)+...+1=1-1$$
$$0-1+...+1=1-1$$
$$0=0 \\ which\,\,is\,\,true\,\,the\,\,left\,\,hand\,\,side\,\,is\,\,zero\,\,when\,\,k\,\,is\,\,2.$$ 
Now the Induction Step: $k=k+1$ on left hand side
$$F_{k+1-2}+F_{k+1-4}+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
$$F_{k-1}+F_{k-3}+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
As we know that $F_{k-1}=F_{k+1}+F_{k}$ and $F_{k-3}=2F_{k+1}-3F_{k}$ therefore,
$$F_{k+1}+F_{k}+2F_{k+1}-3F_{k}+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
$$(F_{k+1}+2F_{k+1})+(F_{k}-3F_{k})+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
$$(3F_{k+1})+(-2F_{k})+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
$$3F_{k+1}-2F_{k}+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: @SK19 
$$F_{k-2}+F_{k-4}+...+F_{k\,mod\,2+2}=F_{k-1}-1, \quad \quad if\: k\geq2.$$

This formula is to prove by induction on $k$

Comment: @robjohn
I have already attempted the problem for the answer and post it as an answer to this post just to clarify that I did right or there are some errors. So, in that case, I am looking for someone to review it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that the answer was yours. It is best to include this in the question as you have now done. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn Can you please review this induction step $k=k+1$ where I need to deduce the series. I need your valuable suggestions if anything went wrong. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we agree on understanding the meaning of the dots
" ... $F_{k-2}+F_{k-4}+F_{k-6}+F_{k-8}+\cdots$ and so on **till** $F_{k\,mod\,2+2}$".

Now we shall agree on the meaning of "**till**".

Using the dots leads to assume (as a standard interpretation) that you mean to say
$$
F_{\,k - 2}  + F_{\,k - 4}  +  \cdots  + F_{\,k\bmod 2 + 2} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} {F_{\,k - 2j} } 
$$
and the standard interpretation of this sum is that, whenever
the index does not respect the conditions imposed, then the sum is considered null, e.g.
$$
\sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, \le \,b} {f(k)} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, \le \,b\quad \left| {\;b\, < \,a} \right.} {f(k)}  = \sum\limits_{k\, \in \;\emptyset } {f(k)}  = 0
$$

There is [another interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773459) of the sum allowing for the bounds
to be reversed, but you do not use dots to indicate it.

Coming to your problem, since
$$
\eqalign{
  & k - 2j = k\bmod 2 + 2\quad  \Rightarrow \quad   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 2j = k - k\bmod 2 - 2 = 2\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  + k\bmod 2 - k\bmod 2 - 2  \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad j = \left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1 \cr} 
$$
Then we write your recurrence as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
F_{\,k - 1}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} {F_{\,k - 2j} } \quad \left| {\;2 \le k} \right.
} \tag{1}$$
and, it seems that, the thesis you want to demonstrate is :

> if the $F_k$ obeys the Fibonacci recurrence $F_{k+1}=F_{k}+F_{k-1} \quad | \; 2 \le k$
>   then they obey to the recurrence above.

The starting conditions are
$$
\eqalign{
  & k = 2\quad  \Rightarrow \quad F_{\,1}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,0} {F_{\,2 - 2j} }  = 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad F_{\,1}  = 1  \cr 
  & k = 3\quad  \Rightarrow \quad F_{\,2}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,0} {F_{\,3 - 2j} }  = 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad F_{\,2}  = 1 \cr} 
$$
which indicates that actually  $F_1 \; F_2$ equal the respective Fibonacci N..  But let's proceed apart from initial conditions
because in the thesis we did not involve the initial conditions, but only the recurrence.

We can put
$$
k = 2m + i\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;1 \le m \hfill \cr 
  \;i = 0,1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and write the system
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  F_{\,2m - 1}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right)} }  \hfill \cr 
  F_{\,2m}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1} }  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  F_{\,2m}  + F_{\,2m - 1}  - 2 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {\left( {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right)}  + F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1} } \right)}  \hfill \cr 
  F_{\,2m}  - F_{\,2m - 1}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {\left( {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1}  - F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right)} } \right)}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
} \tag{2}$$
since the validity of a system implies the validity of the system of the sum and difference of the single lines.

So if the $F$ obeys the Fibonacci recurrence, then the first reads
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & F_{\,2m}  + F_{\,2m - 1}  - 2 = F_{\,2m + 1}  - 2 = F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 1}  - 2 =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {\left( {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right)}  + F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1} } \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 2} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 2j} }
  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m + 1 - 2} {F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 2j} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\,1\, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{{2\left( {m + 1} \right)} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1 - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 2j} }
  = \sum\limits_{\,1\, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{{2\left( {m + 1} \right)} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1}
 {F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 2j} }  - F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 2\left( {\left\lfloor {{{2\left( {m + 1} \right)} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\,1\, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 2j} }  - F_{\,2} \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 1}  - 2 = \sum\limits_{\,1\, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1}
 {F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 2j} }  - F_{\,2}  = \sum\limits_{\,1\, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m + 1} \right) - 2j} }  - 1\quad TRUE \cr} 
} \tag{3.a}$$
while the second line reads
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & F_{\,2m}  - F_{\,2m - 1}  = F_{\,2m - 2}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {\left( {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1}  - F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right)} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {\left( {F_{\,2m - 1 - 2j} } \right)}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{{2m - 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} {\left( {F_{\,2m - 1 - 2j} } \right)}  \quad TRUE \cr} 
} \tag{3.b}$$

*-----   Answer to your comment  -----*

If you want to restate the above in a "classical" induction process, then you can put

1) Thesis 
$$
{\rm Fibonacci}\;{\rm Rec}{\rm .}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left( 1 \right)
$$

2) Initial Match

Since the recurrence is of degree two (it involves $\Delta _{\,k} ^{\,2} F_{\,k} $) then you need to fix two initial conditions, and we saw that
$$
{\rm Thesis}\;{\rm TRUE}\quad \left| {\;k = 2,3} \right.
$$

3) True for $k=2m-1,2m$ implies true for $k=2m,2m+1$

$$
\left\{ {\matrix{
   {F_{\,2m - 1}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right)} } } &  \Leftrightarrow  & {F_{\,2m}  - 1
 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1} } }  \cr 
   {F_{\,2m}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1} } } &  \Leftrightarrow  & {F_{\,2m + 1}  - 1
 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 2} } }  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$
i.e.
$$
\left\{ {\matrix{
   {F_{\,2m - 1}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right)} } } &  \Leftrightarrow  & {F_{\,2m}  - 1
 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1} } }  \cr 
   {F_{\,2m}  - 1 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right) + 1} } } &  \Leftrightarrow  & {F_{\,2m - 1}  - 1
 = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,m - 1} {F_{\,2\left( {m - j} \right)} } }  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$
and thus
$$
{\rm Thesis}\;{\rm TRUE}\quad \left| {\;k = 2,3} \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad {\rm Thesis}\;{\rm TRUE}\quad \left| {\;k = 2m,2m + 1\quad \left| {\;1 \le m} \right.} \right.
$$

Comment: One problem might be that it should be $$ F_{2m}-1=\sum_{1\le j\le m-1}F_{2(m-j)\color{#C00}{+}1} $$

Comment: @robjohn: oh yes, that is, a dull typo : thanks indeed for the help

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooqQaisar: ok, so I added the answer to your comment. Is that in line with your expectation ?

Answer (score 2):

The question can be rewritten as
$$
F_{n-1}-1=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-2}2\right\rfloor}F_{2k+(n\bmod2)}\tag1
$$
For $n=2$ or $n=3$, the sum on the right side of $(1)$ is an empty sum and the left hand side of $(1)$ is $0$. For these two cases, $(1)$ holds.

Suppose that $(1)$ holds. Adding $F_n$ to both sides gives
$$
F_{n+1}-1=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor}F_{2k+(n\bmod2)}\tag2
$$
the left side follows by the recurrence $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ and the right side follows because $F_{2\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor+(n\bmod2)}=F_n$ for both $n$ even and $n$ odd. Since $(2)$ is $(1)$ for $n\mapsto n+2$, $(1)$ follows for all $n\ge2$, even and odd.

---

We can combine the parallel inductions above as a single induction. Break $(1)$ into $P(m)$:
$$
\begin{align}
F_{2m-1}-1&=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}F_{2k}\tag3\\
F_{2m}-1&=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}F_{2k+1}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
$P(1)$ is simply
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{F_1-1\vphantom{\sum_{k=1}^0}}^0&=\overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^0F_{2k}}^0\tag5\\
F_2-1&=\sum_{k=1}^0F_{2k+1}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Now suppose that $P(m)$ is true. Add $F_{2m}$ to both sides of $(3)$ and $F_{2m+1}$ to both sides of $(4)$. We get
$$
\begin{align}
F_{2m+1}-1&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}F_{2k}\tag7\\
F_{2m+2}-1&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}F_{2k+1}\tag8
\end{align}
$$
which is $P(m+1)$.

This completes the induction.

Comment: well, the thing is we need to follow the induction rule by applying $k=k+1$ as an Inductive step to deduce the equation as much as we can, where I had attempted to answer. I hope you will get my point. Regards!

Comment: It is easier to prove the statement for the evens and then prove it for the odds. Trying to do it for all at once is going to be more difficult.

Comment: Your approach by changing the summation index is very smart, and the rest of the proof is right and very concise (+1) ! So there is a fault in my answer, but I do not succeed and get it: may I ask your help in that ?

Answer (score 1):

I have attempted to solve this problem using induction, Please if anyone confirms that my attempt is true for induction step. Or If someone helps me with this answer if anything goes wrong.

$$F_{k-2}+F_{k-4}+...+F_{k\,mod\,2+2}=F_{k-1}-1 \quad \quad if\,k\geq2$$

My Attempt:
Base case $k=2$
$$F_{2-2}+F_{2-4}+...+F_{2\,mod \,2+2}=F_{2-1}-1$$
As $2\, mod\,2=0$
therefore,
$$F_{0}+F_{-2}+...+F_{0+2}=F_{1}-1$$
$$F_{0}+F_{-2}+...+F_{2}=F_{1}-1$$
As $F_{0}=0,\,F_{-2}=-1,\,F_{2}=1,\,and\,F_{1}=1\,$therefore,
$$0+(-1)+...+1=1-1$$
$$0-1+...+1=1-1$$
$$0=0 \\ which\,\,is\,\,true\,\,the\,\,left\,\,hand\,\,side\,\,is\,\,zero\,\,when\,\,k\,\,is\,\,2.$$ 
Now the Induction Step: $k=k+1$ on left hand side
$$F_{k+1-2}+F_{k+1-4}+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
$$F_{k-1}+F_{k-3}+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
As we know that $F_{k-1}=F_{k+1}+F_{k}$ and $F_{k-3}=2F_{k+1}-3F_{k}$ therefore,
$$F_{k+1}+F_{k}+2F_{k+1}-3F_{k}+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
$$(F_{k+1}+2F_{k+1})+(F_{k}-3F_{k})+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
$$(3F_{k+1})+(-2F_{k})+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$
$$3F_{k+1}-2F_{k}+...+F_{k+1\,mod\,2+2}$$

Comment: It is not clear what is the meaning assigned (by you/by me) to the dots in $F_{k-2}+F_{k-4}+...+F_{k\,mod\,2+2}$. My best understanding is that you are decreasing from $k-2$ down to $k\,mod\,2+2$ in steps of $2$: e.g. for $k=8$ then $6,4,2$ and **stop** there. Then for $k=2$ you should have $0$ on the LHS, since you cannot **decrease** from $0$ to $2$ ! What is your interpretation instead ?

Comment: @GCab Well its a series which goes on $F_{k-2}+F_{k-4}+F_{k-6}+F_{k-8}+$ and so on till $F_{k\,mod\,2+2}$
The thing is that I need to prove this by Induction so the base case was true on $k=2$, I only need your valuable time to review the Induction step where I put $k=k+1$ to deduced this series, I hope you will clear with that.
I will wait for your kind suggestions, regards!